# Why Android can handle only one active Internet connection?

Tags: android, android-networking

I encountered with strange issue in Android.I use this code to get the information about all Internet connections:

```
    NetworkInfo[] info = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo networkInfo : info)
    {
        Log.d("LOG","networkInfo = " + networkInfo);
    }
```

I test this on my device on which I turn on WiFi connection and have an active mobile Internet (EDGE). But in shows:`type: mobile[EDGE], state: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED` and `type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED` but when I turn off WiFi it shows `type: mobile[EDGE], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED`.

Can someone explain me this strange behavior.It seems Android can handle only one connection in spite of there are several ones active (and it always prefer WiFi connection over EDGE). Is there some workaround?Or may be it is a bug?

Comment: What do you need more than one connection for?

Comment: @jlordo I don't need but I'm interesting in this issue and want explanation.It seems weird to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone explain me this strange behavior.

Android uses WiFi if it is available. Otherwise, it uses mobile data.

> It seems Android can handle only one connection in spite of there several ones active.

Android normally only uses one connection at a time. In most of the world, mobile data is metered, and so if WiFi is available, Android uses it, to reduce the cost to the user.

The OS is capable of using multiple connections at once (see the WiFi hot-spot facility), but for normal operations, only one connection is necessary.

Comment: Thanks.`The OS is capable of using multiple connections at once ` but then why `NetworkInfo` tells EDGE is DISCONNECTED if it is always connected.Ok Android prefer WiFi and it seems rational.But why it doesn't show other connections is active at all?It seems strange to me...

Comment: @HarryCater Because other connections are disconnected to conserve battery life. There is no point in keeping EDGE active if it is not being used.

Comment: @RaghavSood But on the status bar EDGE indicator tells EDGE is active.So it seems it is not actually disabled when WiFi is active

Comment: @HarryCater I can't see the same on any of my devices. Are you sure your device is connected to the WiFi, and that you can see EDGE as Active, and not merely normal mobile connections

Comment: @RaghavSood Sorry. Yes I see now. thanks to all guys you really clarify this thing for me